# Resizing a window to a set size in Linux

Tags: linux

Anyone knows a good way to resize any window to for example 640x480?

Reason is, of course, screencasting.

Under windows I've used ZoneSize from donationcoder. (Btw: For Firefox it's easy, just use the web developer toolbar.)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the [wmctrl](http://www.sweb.cz/tripie/utils/wmctrl/) command:

To list the windows:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x00c00003 -1 rgamble-desktop Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x00c00031 -1 rgamble-desktop Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x00e00022 -1 rgamble-desktop Desktop
0x0260007c  0 rgamble-desktop Google - Mozilla Firefox
```

To resize a window based on its title:

```
wmctrl -r Firefox -e 0,0,0,640,480
```

The arguments to the resize option are `gravity,X,Y,width,height` so this will place the window at the top-left corner of the screen and resize it to 640X480.

Comment: btw, you can add `-G` (i.e. `wmctrl -l -G`) to get current geometries as well.

Comment: you can also specify the window with `-r ':SELECT:'`. That way, you can point and click the window that you want to resize.

Answer (score 4):

Using wmctrl, there is also some pre defined states:

If a window is currently in the state `maximized`, it won't respond to a resizing in pixels using the `-e` parameter^. This is where the `-b` param is useful.

> The -b option expects a list of comma separated parameters:
>   "(remove|add|toggle),PROP1,PROP2]"

Example:

```
wmctrl -r Firefox -b toggle,maximized_horz
```

States available:

```
wmctrl -r Firefox -b toggle,maximized_vert
                     -----  ---------------
                     remove  modal
                     add     sticky
                     toggle  maximized_vert
                             maximized_horz
                             shaded
                             skip_taskbar
                             skip_pager
                             hidden
                             fullscreen
                             above
                             below
```

---

About the precise question, the -e param allow resizing by values as follow:

Gravity, position X, position Y, window width, window height

```
// gravity,x,y,w,h
wmctrl -r "Resizing" -e 0,0,0,640,480
```

Answer (score 2):

sh script that uses wmctrl to resize windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
wmctrl -l
echo
read -p "window id -> " wid
read -p "width -> " ww
read -p "height -> " wh
wmctrl -i -r "$wid" -e "0,0,0,$ww,$wh"
echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

`wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -e "0,$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry|egrep -o '[0-9]+,[^ ]+'),970,600"`

targets an **active** window (i.e, the terminal used for the command)
resizes to 970 (**width**) and 600 (**height**)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).